# How to hightlight an item in one listbox based on selection on the other listbox using wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am doing my first project by using wpf/mvvm and get stuck here. I really need your help and suggestion. Thanks in advance.

I am doing a report filter building screen, which allow the user to create and maintain a list of filters. the ReportFilter object has four properties: status, party, absencecode & fitlername, getting from database. Whenever a user select a filter by clicking filtername in a listbox, the associated status(a group of radio buttons), party(a group of radio buttons) & absencecode(a listbox containing a list of absence code) will be checked/highlighted. I can make radio buttons checked based on selection. But can't highlight the item in listbox for absencecode. When debugging, I can get selectedFilter.AbsenceCode for listbox of absencecode in Convert(). But I don't know how to compare the value from the list and highlight it. Like what param to pass to ConverterParameter for comparing?

Following is some of my code:

```
public class ReportFilter : ModelBase
{
    String _Status;
    String _Party;
    String _AbsenseCode;
    String _FilterName;

    public String AbsenseCode
    {
        get { return _AbsenseCode; }
        set
        {
            if (_AbsenseCode == value)
                return;
            _AbsenseCode = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AbsenseCode");
        }
    }
    ....
 }


public class ReportsViewModel : ModelBase
{
    private ReportFilter _selectedFilter;
    public ReportFilter selectedFilter
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedFilter;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedFilter = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("selectedFilter");
        }
    }
 ......
```

Following is xaml code:

```
    <!-- absence code list -->
    <ListBox Name="Absence
Code" ItemsSource="{Binding absenseCodeItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding seletedFilter.AbsenseCode,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="5" Margin="20,0,20,5" >
       <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
          <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
             <Setter Property="IsSelected"  Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.selectedFilter.AbsenseCode, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type GroupBox}},  Converter={StaticResource IsItemSelected}, ConverterParameter=}"/>
           </Style>
       </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>

    <!-- filter list -->
    <ListBox Name="FilterListbox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=filterItems}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.Column="2" Margin="20,0,20,5"  SelectedItem="{Binding selectedFilter, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    </ListBox>
```

A group of radio buttons for status:

```
<RadioButton GroupName="Group1" Name="Current"  Grid.Column="0" Foreground="White" Content="Current" Margin="10,0,0,0" IsChecked="{Binding Path=selectedFilter.Status, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToStringValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=C}"/>

<RadioButton GroupName="Group2" Name="Historical" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="White" Content="All Historical" IsChecked="{Binding Path=selectedFilter.Status, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToStringValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=A}"/>
```

......

Convertor in view model:

```
.....
    public class IsItemSelected : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (System.Convert.ToString(value).Equals(System.Convert.ToString(parameter)))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
.....
```

Comment: you should also post XAML and view models that you're using. a screenshot might help too.

Comment: The content(XAML) got cut off? why? And how can I put them in? First time using Stackoverflow.

Comment: it shouldn't have? Make sure it's formatted correctly i guess?

Comment: You should not bind both SelectedItem and SelectedIndex in filter list. This may cause conflicts. By the way SelectedItem reffers to the ListBoxItem that is selected. You probably want SelectedValue instead.

Comment: I am taking SelectedIndex off. Thanks. I tried SelectedValue, still the same. I don't know how I can let Convert() work?